# Can't load existing js file on gh-pages

Tags: github, routes, http-status-code-404, github-pages

My index.html (https://srgg6701.github.io/Music-Is-My-Life/) can't see 3 existing .js files, although I can load them directly in raw mode. They are here: https://github.com/srgg6701/Music-Is-My-Life/tree/gh-pages/js/_libs 
What may be cause of this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. Are you still seeing a problem?

Comment: It seems that gh-pages doesn't understand directory name starting from underscore. I had removed this symbol and then it recognized everything.

Comment: Understood. See my answer for an explanation on why this happened, as well as some workarounds for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Jekyll (which GitHub Pages uses to generate your pages) ignores anything that starts with an underscore.

You can change this setting by modifying your settings, as discussed [here](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/):

> If your GitHub Pages site isn't publishing certain files then you
>   might need to reformat their titles. If you are using Jekyll you can
>   create a *.nojekyll* file or edit the *_config.yml* file to publish
>   these files.
>
> By default, Jekyll does not build any files or directories that
>
> - are hidden or used for backup (indicated by names that start with `.` or `#`, or that end with `~`);
> - contain site content (indicated by names that start with `_`); or
> - are excluded in the [site configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#global-configuration).
>
> To work around this behavior, you can
>
> - include a *.nojekyll* file in the root path to turn off Jekyll;
> - use [the `include` directive][global-config] in your *_config.yml* to specify files that should not be ignored; or
> - do not use file or directory names that start with an underscore (`_`), period (`.`), or hash symbol (`#`), or that end with a tilde
>     (`~`).