# Sveltekit build failing to find external files on gh pages

Tags: github, tailwind-css, github-pages, svelte, sveltekit

My site refuses to find the rest of the build directory files which is on a separate branch in my GitHub Repo.
[image: gh-pages branch in github]
Any files in the _app folder is not being found when I go to the site.
[image: broken webpage]

As you can see all the get requests are failing for the page
[image: get requests failing]
It works better on local, but not really; Apparently the tailwindCSS loads but the js still doesn't;
[image: local breaking too]
Any suggestions or help are much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Underscores, not only in folder names, but in all file names was the culprit. Make sure to get rid of them if you're using SvelteKit!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SvelteKit deployment on gh - pages doesn't work. Only HTML is shown, CSS and JS doesn't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497065/sveltekit-deployment-on-gh-pages-doesnt-work-only-html-is-shown-css-and-js)

Comment: Second the comment above. Additionally, we'd need a way to reproduce it or to look at the given code to be able to reliably help, with just screenshots we can only guess at the cause.

Comment: I already had a look at that question, it's basically the same issue but I haven't be able to reproduce the success they had. Those steps did not fix it for me.

I can't share too much code due to company policy and naturally I understand that means it's unlikely anyone can help too much, but I still felt it worth giving it a shot :)

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to elaborate on OP's edit, I ran into the same issue where it was the underscore in the folder name, specifically _app. My `svelte.config.js` ended up looking like this.

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        appDir: 'app',
        adapter: adapter(),
        paths: {
            base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/<project_name>' : ''
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

Where I set `appDir` to just `app`.

Answer (score 0):

> Turns out that the problem is that in my svelte.config.js I had paths:
> { base: dev ? '' : '/my-portfolio', } because it was needed by GitHub
> in order to make it work. Apparently now it doesn't need it anymore,
> so all the 404 were right since it was trying to get non-existing
> files.

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/52062

Try removing the paths that you might have configured in svelte.config.js