# Why is my github page only showing a blank screen with Svelte + Vite?

Tags: node.js, github, github-pages, svelte, vite

Here are the steps I took condensed:

- Published my project using VSCode's publish repo button.
- added the npm command: `npm run deploy` => `npx gh-pages -d dist`
- ran `npm run build`
- ran `npm run deploy`
- added "`base:"/lilys-website/",`" into the file `vite.config.js`
- ran `npm run build` & `npm run deploy` again

The issue is that my page is only loading in the CSS but not the JS from what I can guess. It's only showing a blank screen.
Looking at DevTools doesn't help as there isn't any errors for not being able to load a file.

Steps taken are from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-PTp1rmr30

Repo: https://github.com/DoormatIka/lilys-website

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SvelteKit deployment on gh - pages doesn't work. Only HTML is shown, CSS and JS doesn't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497065/sveltekit-deployment-on-gh-pages-doesnt-work-only-html-is-shown-css-and-js)

Answer (score 0):

**Fix your routes.**
This applies to SvelteKit and Svelte + Vite.

Bad:

```js
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={Main}/>
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
</Router>
```

Good:

```js
<Router>
  <Route path="/[REPO NAME]" component={Main}/>
  <Route path="/[REPO NAME]/about" component={About} />
</Router>
```