# Github Pages - Svelte -> /_app/immutable/*

Tags: github-pages, sveltekit

I deployed my svelte app to github pages, but the /_app/immutable/* directory keeps getting a 404 error. I'm guessing this has something to do with security added to the endpoints? How do I fix this issue.

https://github.com/kakhil2004/simpleport2/tree/gh-pages

and the link to my page itself. You can see in the network tab in devtools that I keep getting 404.

https://kakhil2004.github.io/simpleport2/

This is not an issue when I am running the build locally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SvelteKit deployment on gh - pages doesn't work. Only HTML is shown, CSS and JS doesn't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497065/sveltekit-deployment-on-gh-pages-doesnt-work-only-html-is-shown-css-and-js)

Comment: It worked actually. I had .nojekyll in my static folder but for some reason it wasn't there when I uploaded to my gh-pages branch. That fixed everything thanks!